# Connecting load to SSR - Doubts regarding load position

Tags: solid-state-relay

I am using a solid state relay to control supply to a load.

I would like to provide ground to the load all the time. When the SSR is turned ON (8.4 V will become available to the load). [In the datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TLP3106A_datasheet_en_20191226-1893334.pdf), they have mentioned different types of connections. I am using TYPE C (shorting pin 4 and 6, for more current ratings.)

In this case, the load will always be connected to 8 V. Only when SSR is ON will the ground be connected to the load. I do not want this. I want the ground to be always available. Please refer to the attached image.

Is this type of connection acceptable?

[image]

The below picture is how, I would like to wire, so that Load is always connected to the ground. **is this acceptable?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. You need to connect the load this way. Now the SSR output is in the battery positive and the load is connected to battery negative.*

With the arrangement of Figure 1 you can now connect the battery negative to your control circuit COM.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz0rDw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Common ground between two supplies and the load.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6GC8a.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Equivalent circuit.*

Comment: Connecting the battery positive to ground is valid too. The original proposed circuit would work.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for common negative for supplies and load.

Answer (score 1):

I do think, you should connect it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM4UWA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>